# Call javascript function from different page on different pages

Tags: javascript

My brother's Bar Mitzvah is in a few months and I am trying to make a synchronized intro animation that is set to a timer. My plan is for two display screens to display different images and for the DJ to have a screen where he/she can set a timer, a function call being sent to different pages.

Currently what I am trying to do is test (in real time) the body being clicked on "right.html" and changing the body color on "left.html"

Here is my javascript code:

```
function changecolor(){
  document.getElementById('left').style.background = red;
}
```

Left body tag:

```
<body id="left">
```

Right body tag:

```
<body onclick="changecolor()" id="right">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need some way to communicate between the pages. They have no knowledge of each other.

Comment: `changecolor` is not a function call.

Comment: The functionality you describe is quite advanced. And it's too broad to give a good answer here. Also sounds like (no offence) your technical level is way below the skill level required for functionality you want to create. But it might be a good challenge. Simple socket based solution: Firebase. Check it out for simple real time communication.

Comment: This functionality is not "advanced" nor does it require sockets.  For two different windows on the same machine, use [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Comment: To set the color correctly use `document.getElementById('left').style.background = 'red';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this with local storage to change the colors of different pages in the same browser:

**On the page that needs to set change colors** on other pages add this:

```
// Store background color
function changecolor(){
    localStorage.setItem("background", "red");
}
```

**On the pages that need to get the color**:

```
// Loop every half a second, until the color is set
var intervalObj = setInterval(function(){ 
    // Check for background value
    var background = localStorage.getItem("background");

    // If background is set, use it and unset it
    if(background != "undefined" && background != null){
        // Dev notify
        console.log('Background setting to ' + background + '.');
        // Stop unnecessary interval
        clearInterval(intervalObj);

        // Set the background color
        document.getElementById('left').style.background = background;

        // Unset the variable
        localStorage.setItem("background", "undefined");
    }else{
        // Dev, notify if still didn't receive the color
        console.log("Waiting for page to be clicked...");
    }
}, 500);
```

**Note:** use different variables for different pages. The same variable won't work on more than one page. You can use different variables for different pages e.g. 'background_page1', 'background_page2' etc to have other pages change colors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use localstorage

The storage event fires when other tabs makes changes to localStorage. This is quite handy for communication purposes.
[Web storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

You can get the value to use to set the style of an element:

```
function setStyles() {
  var currentColor = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');
  var currentFont = localStorage.getItem('font');
  var currentImage = localStorage.getItem('image');

  document.getElementById('bgcolor').value = currentColor;
  document.getElementById('font').value = currentFont;
  document.getElementById('image').value = currentImage;

  htmlElem.style.backgroundColor = '#' + currentColor;
  pElem.style.fontFamily = currentFont;
  imgElem.setAttribute('src', currentImage);
}
```

Comment: Actually I am looking for it to be on the same machine. Looking into the response now